# Scraping multiple pages from a website into a csv file

Tags: python, csv, web, url, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from multiple pages of the same URL into one single csv file ;)

The way this script works is by writing the url into a url.txt file, the script will read from this file then save it into a csv file

I am trying to figure out on my own, but I need the help of the bright minds of this community to please help me out

As you can see in the code, I am trying to **scrape** data from kakaku.com (jp website)

```
'''
import os
   import sys
   import csv
   import codecs
   import requests
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


   # scraping function for kakatu.com / old version             
   def kakaku_scraper_o(url):   
    for u in url:
        headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebkit/537.36         (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'}
        page = requests.get(u, headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

        titles_temp = soup.find_all(class_ = "ckitemLink")
        prices_temp = soup.find_all(class_ = "pryen")
        links_temp = soup.find_all(class_ = "ckitanker")
        titles = []
        prices = []
        links = []
        for i in range(len(titles_temp)):
            links.append(links_temp[i]['href'])
            titles.append(titles_temp[i].get_text())
            prices.append(prices_temp[i].get_text())
                    
        filename = u.split("/")
        filename = filename[-2] + "_kakaku.csv"
        with open(filename, 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline='') as csvFile:
            csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
            csvWriter.writerow(["Link", "Title", "Price"])
            for i in range(len(titles)):
                csvWriter.writerow([links[i], titles[i].encode("utf8"), prices[i].encode("utf8")])
     
 
# scraping function for kakatu.com / new version             
def kakaku_scraper_n(url):   
    for u in url:
        headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebkit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'}
        page = requests.get(u, headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

        titles_temp = soup.find_all(class_ = "p-list_name")
        prices_temp = soup.find_all(class_ = "p-list_price_data_price_num-1 p-num")
        links_temp = soup.find_all(class_ = 'p-list_name')
        
        titles = []
        prices = []
        links = []
        for i in range(len(titles_temp)):
            links_temp[i] = links_temp[i].find("a")
            links.append("https://kakaku.com" + str(links_temp[i]['href']))
            titles.append(titles_temp[i].get_text())
            prices.append(prices_temp[i].get_text())

        filename = u.split("/")
        filename = filename[-2] + "_kakaku.csv"
        with open(filename, 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline='') as csvFile:
            csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
            csvWriter.writerow(["Link", "Title", "Price"])
            for i in range(len(titles)):
                csvWriter.writerow([links[i], titles[i], prices[i]])


# scraping fuction for bestgate.net
def bestgate_scraper(url):
    for u in url:
        headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebkit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'}
        page = requests.get(u, headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

        titles_temp = soup.find_all(class_ = "name")
        prices_temp = soup.find_all(class_ = "price")
        links_temp = soup.find_all(class_ = 'name')
        
        titles = []
        prices = []
        links = []
        for i in range(len(titles_temp)):
            links.append(links_temp[i]['href'])
            titles.append(titles_temp[i].get_text())
            prices.append(prices_temp[i].get_text())

        filename = u.split("/")
        filename = filename[-2] + "_bestgate.csv"`enter code here`
        with open(filename, 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline='') as csvFile:
            csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
            csvWriter.writerow(["Link", "Title", "Price"])
            for i in range(len(titles)):
                csvWriter.writerow([links[i], titles[i], prices[i]])


# main function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("url.txt", mode='r', newline='') as urlfile:
        url = urlfile.read().splitlines()
        print(url)
        urlfile.close()
        
    # sort out the links for each website's function
    kko = []
    kkn = []
    btg = []
    for u in url:
        if not "aspx" in u:
            if "kakaku" in u:
                kkn.append(u)
        elif "aspx" and "kakaku" in u:
                kko.append(u)
        else:
            btg.append(u)
            
    bestgate_scraper(btg)
    
    kakaku_scraper_o(kko)
    
    kakaku_scraper_n(kkn)
'''
```

Comment: These are the urls i am trying to scrap which are written within the url.txt filehttps://kakaku.com/keitai/smartphone/?pdf_Spec106=2&pdf_pg=1
https://kakaku.com/keitai/smartphone/?pdf_Spec106=2&pdf_pg=2
https://kakaku.com/keitai/smartphone/?pdf_Spec106=2&pdf_pg=3
https://kakaku.com/keitai/smartphone/?pdf_Spec106=2&pdf_pg=4
https://kakaku.com/keitai/smartphone/?pdf_Spec106=2&pdf_pg=5

Answer (score 0):

I don't completly understand your question.
But I will make the following observation:

1. Mark code in the question as python code, so is easier to read
2. Make code as modular as possible.
3. Make clear with is your doubt.

If you update your question I may help you.

Comment: Thank you, for your feedback. I'm sorry I am new to this

Comment: My question is that I am trying to scrap a name list at smartphone_kakaku, the page has multiple pages and I just want to scrap the name of the list of smartphones into one csv file, currently I am able to just scrap just one page at a time

Comment: You want to make yout script multithearding?